# Does making a column unique force an index to be created?

Tags: sql, sql-server

In SQL Server 2005+ (I use both), does adding the `UNIQUE` constraint to a column automatically create an index, or should I still `CREATE INDEX`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

See this [MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177420.aspx):

> The Database Engine automatically
>   creates a UNIQUE index to enforce the
>   uniqueness requirement of the UNIQUE
>   constraint.

If you do create an index, you'll end up with two indexes, as this example demonstrates:

```
create table TestTable (id int)
alter table TestTable add constraint unique_id unique (id)
create unique index ix_TestTable_id on TestTable (id)

select * from sys.indexes where [object_id] = object_id('TestTable')
```

This will display two unique indexes on TestTable; and the HEAP that represents the table itself.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it does.

In fact, you can even create a `CLUSTERED UNIQUE CONSTRAINT`:

```
ALTER TABLE mytable ADD CONSTRAINT UX_mytable_col1 UNIQUE CLUSTERED (col1)
```

, which will make the table to be clustered on `col1`.

Almost all databases create an index for `UNIQUE CONSTRAINT`, otherwise it would be very hard to maintain it.

`Oracle` doesn't even distinguish between `UNIQUE CONSTRAINT` and `UNIQUE INDEX`: one command is just a synonym for another.

The only difference in `Oracle` is that a `UNIQUE INDEX` should have a user-supplied name, while a `UNIQUE CONSTRAINT` may be created with a system-generated name:

```
ALTER TABLE mytable MODIFY col1 UNIQUE
```

This will create an index called `SYS_CXXXXXX`.

Comment: When you make a column unique, Oracle will not create the unique index if the column is already indexed - because it can police a unique constraint with a non-unique index (although this is not normally recommended).

Comment: Just checked, the clustered constraint works on sql server too, replacing the HEAP in my example

Comment: @Andomar: yes, it's SQL Server I wrote about describing a clustered constraint :) Oracle calls this thing an INDEX ORGANIZED TABLE.

Answer (score 1):

An index is created when you add a unique constraint:

[Reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177420.aspx) -- see the second paragraph.

> When a UNIQUE constraint is added to
>   an existing column or columns in the
>   table, by default, the Database Engine
>   examines the existing data in the
>   columns to make sure all values are
>   unique. If a UNIQUE constraint is
>   added to a column that has duplicated
>   values, the Database Engine returns an
>   error and does not add the constraint.
>
> The Database Engine automatically
>   creates a UNIQUE index to enforce the
>   uniqueness requirement of the UNIQUE
>   constraint. Therefore, if an attempt
>   to insert a duplicate row is made, the
>   Database Engine returns an error
>   message that states the UNIQUE
>   constraint has been violated and does
>   not add the row to the table. Unless a
>   clustered index is explicitly
>   specified, a unique, nonclustered
>   index is created by default to enforce
>   the UNIQUE constraint.